# Webscraping an AJAX response using python

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping

I am trying to get information of different metal prices from a website that shows that information for free (https://www.wieland.com/en/metal-information#tab-general). I have achieved it by using Python+Selenium but I am aware that there are more efficient ways (such as getting the information directly from the AJAX response). I have found the information I want to get by using FireFox Dev Tools but I cannot find a way to import that information to python directly.

The aim is to get the information from the date and price into python and then create a dataframe using Pandas

For example, the steps I followed in order to get the AJAX responses were:

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

If someone could guide me on this topic, I would appreciate it

Comment: I don't see those XHR requests being generated when I enter the URL you posted. What did you do precisely to get those AJAX requests generated. Or at least specify the full URL of one of those requests instead of an image showing a partial URL.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback, I have updated my post showing how those AJAX requests were generated. The URL does not really change in the process flow I did above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing to the network requests for the above website looks like we need to get cookies consent on another URL and to get that table data in `Dataframe` we would use `read_html` function of pandas and to send request we would be using requests library.

Edit Their is no need to send cookie consent request without that you could directly send xhr request.

```
import requests
from pandas import read_html

headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
querystring = {
    "type": "general",
    "method": "getDetails",
    "language": "en",
    "refKey": "2101",
    "interval": "1",
    "intervalStart": "09.01.2021",
    "intervalEnd": "09.04.2021",
}
data = requests.get("https://www.wieland.com/en/ajax-metal-prices",headers=headers,params=querystring)
if data.status_code == 200:
    table = read_html(data.json()["content"]["template"], attrs={"class": "metalinfo-table"})[0]
    print(table)
else:
    print("Some Issue")
```

table variable have your `Dataframe` for that table.

Output:

[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! It was very helpful!! However, as I have just started learning about webscraping, I would get more familiar about the ethics of using it. For example, on this specific case, I am planning to create a loop in order to get the prices for Cu, Zn, Ni, etc. but would this affect the website somehow?(i.e. create too much traffic that it might fail)

Comment: usually websites wont fail like this as I don't think you would scraping hell lot of data and want just some of it and even scraping hell lot of data it would fulfill it as it is kept online to give data only.